# Delete empty lines in file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to delete empty lines from a file. Currently it deletes all except for the one I add at line 35:`out_file << data_vector[i] << "\n";`

How do I exclude the last `"\n"` so it doesn't add a new line?

Here's the full function:

```
std::vector<std::string> Data::Data::ReadData() {

    std::regex find_empty_line("^(\\s*)$");
    std::smatch match;

    std::string data, fel;
    std::vector<std::string> data_vector;

    std::ifstream in_file;
    in_file.open(file_name);

    if (in_file.is_open()) {
        while (in_file.good()) {
            std::getline(in_file, data);
            data_vector.push_back(data);
        }
    }

    in_file.close();

    std::ofstream out_file;
    out_file.open(file_name);

    if (out_file.is_open()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data_vector.size(); ++i) {
            if (!data_vector[i].empty()) {
                out_file << data_vector[i] << "\n";
                std::cout << data_vector[i] << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    out_file.close();

    return data_vector;

}
```

Comment: One solution can be to go up to `data_vector.size() - 1` in the last loop, and add the last line after the loop without the `<< "\n"`. So you will always have a line break except for the last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best practice (on most Operating Systems), and expected by a lot of file processing tools, to have a newline at the end of every line in a file, so you normally wouldn't want to remove the final newline... consider it a line termination character with no line after it, rather than a line separator with an implicit empty line afterwards.

But, if you really must avoid that to work with the tools you're stuck with, then one easy way to avoid outputting it for the last line is to:

```
out_file << data_vector[i] << (i < data_vector.size() - 1) ? "\n" : "");
```

If you're unfamiliar with the ternary conditional operator, the basic form is:

```
conditional-expression ? expression-used-if-true : expression-used-if-false
```

Examples: `(a <= b ? a : b)` evaluates to the minimum of `a` and `b`.  Read more [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) if you need/want.

Then, to make that work, we need to make sure the last line in `data_vector` is the last line of output, which it might not currently be because we have some empty line in there, so let's filter those out while populating the vector (no need to check `good()`):

```
while (std::getline(in_file, data))
    if (!data.empty())
        data_vector.push_back(data);
```

Knowing there are no empty lines in `data_vector` then lets us simplify the output loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data_vector.size(); ++i) {
    out_file << data_vector[i]
             << (i < data_vector.size() - 1) ? "\n" : "");
    std::cout << data_vector[i] << "\n";
}
```

(This does assume you don't want the empty lines in the returned `vector`, either...)

Comment: Thanks a ton; it worked. I will consider leaving an empty line since you said it's best practice.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I exclude the last "\n" so it doesn't add a new line?

By outputting a `\n` only when you have a subsequent line to also output, eg:

```
std::vector<std::string> Data::Data::ReadData() {

    std::vector<std::string> data_vector;

    std::ifstream in_file(file_name);
    if (in_file.is_open()) {
        std::string data;
        while (std::getline(in_file, data)) {
            data_vector.push_back(data);
        }
        in_file.close();
    }

    std::ofstream out_file(file_name);
    if (out_file.is_open()) {
        bool output_line_break = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < data_vector.size(); ++i) {
            if (!data_vector[i].empty()) {
                if (output_line_break) {
                    out_file << '\n';
                }
                else {
                    output_line_break = true;
                }
                out_file << data_vector[i];
                std::cout << data_vector[i] << '\n';
            }
        }
        out_file.close();
    }

    return data_vector;
}
```